# USE COUNT WITH CONDITION IN THE SAME TABLE

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    P.NAME,  L.ID, L.FROM, L.END, L.SALARY, L.NOTE, 
    CASE
        WHEN (MAX(A.END) IS NULL OR MAX(A.END) >= current date ) 
            THEN 'JES' 
            ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS "Have One "
   
FROM 
    SALARY L 
INNER JOIN 
    CONTACT A ON A.ID = L.ID
INNER JOIN 
    Pep P ON P.ID = L.ID 
WHERE
    L.SALARY = '8000' 
    AND L.END >= CURRENT DATE 
GROUP BY  
    P.NAME, L.ID, L.FROM, L.END, L.SALARY, L.NOTE
```

what i want to add new column that contain result : how many  active record by person . i consider record is active when  the following condition is ok

```
L.END >= FIRST_DAY(CURRENT DATE) AND L.FROM <= LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE)
```

example  på result:

```
|  name  |  ID | FROM      |   END    | SALARY | NOTE | HAVE ONE | ACTIVE
|  KLAR  | 678 |2021-01-01 |2021-09-31|   8000 | GOD  |  YES     |   1
|  KLAR  | 678 |2021-10-01 |2021-12-31|   8000 | GOD  |  YES     |   1
|  TINA  | 676 |2021-01-01 |2021-09-31|   8000 | GOD  |  YES     |   2
|  TINA  | 676 |2021-06-01 |2021-12-31|   8000 | GOD  |  YES     |   2
```

How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT when GROUP BY?!? No need to do that, just makes people think your code is strange.

Comment: You have very unintuitive column aliases. I'd chose `S` for `SALARY`, not `L`.

Comment: If we saw the real query we might be able to give further help. You certainly don't join on `A.ID = L.ID` and `P.ID = L.ID` in your real query. And do you really join the pep table without using it? And then you aggregate. Maybe because you multiplied the rows with the pep join? Or why else?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can just use conditional aggregation with your existing logic, implement your new column like so:

```
...,
SUM(
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN L.END >= FIRST_DAY(CURRENT DATE)
          AND L.FROM <= LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE) 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  )
) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS ACTIVE
```

Comment: This  will give me sum for all persons but i want per person . example i have 1000 person in the table and evrery one have more an one row i want to add anew column that discribe how many  active records that belong to this person .

Comment: @Tick_Tack it would help to see actual sample data however possibly you need a windowed aggregate, I have made an edit above - untested of course.

Comment: i added picture from result that i want  look at Dani he has two  record but one of them only active because it is contain this month so i should add 1 in status   ,but calmer has two och  båda are activ because they contain both this month so i should write 2 in the status

Comment: @Tick _Tack: Your first comment is wrong. You don't get a total sum over all persons, but one sum per group. As there are several groups per person, though, you want the sum of the sums for each person. I've edited Stu's answer, so it fits into your query.

Comment: thanks very much to your answer it was so usefull ,but i made change  like delete else 0 if you put it ,it will count 0 with 1  @ThorstenKettner

Comment: @Tick _Tack: No, it won't. Stu's counting is correct. The sum of 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 is 1, not 4. Maybe you changed Stu's `SUM` to `COUNT` in which case `ELSE` must be removed or replaced by `ELSE NULL`, but as long as you work with `SUM` `ELSE 0` is fine. And if this solves your request, then you should accept Stu`s answer by clicking the check/tick next to it.

Comment: EXACT COUNT NOT SUM